# I want to make 2 parent categories and attach to them same sub category

Tags: category

I want to make 2 parent categories and attach to them same sub category
example:

- category name:"gift" --> subcategory name:"photo gift"
- category name:"gift for dad" -->  subcategory name:"photo gift"

Same sub category in 2 different parent categories.

Can it be done in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

No, a sub-category can't be linked to multiple parent categories.

You will have to create two separate sub-categories. So, you would have this category structure:

- Gift

  - Photo gift (1)
- Gift for dad

  - Photo gift (2)

And you would have two 'Photo gift' categories.

However, you can link a product to multiple categories. So, you can configure both sub-categories so that they will look exactly the same.

Comment: Can we able to update same name child category in different parent while re-importing via CSV.

Below is the example.
Default Category:
    =>Mobile
        -Samsung
        -Sony
    =>TV
        -Samsung
        -Sony
    =>Device
        -Samsung
        -Sony